# How to setup a secure communication between desktop app with websocket server and a web page?

Tags: security, ssl, websocket, webclient, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application that starts a websocket server, so that web pages/clients served by other web servers can call the desktop app to perform some actions requiring OS APIs not available to browsers resp. web pages. I intentionally decided not to use native messaging. The web page calls the desktop app via ws://localhost:8765. The connection is initiated by the web page/client. If a web page from a specific web server contacts the desktop app for the first time, the desktop app asks the user if incoming connections from this domain shall be trusted and are allowed to communicate with the desktop app.

To my understanding the data stream through localhost never leaves the hardware system and therefore is not vulnerable to attacks from the outside. But what other security measures should I nevertheless apply?

- Use secure sockets (wss)? I don't want the users to handle certificates. Putting a private key for a SSL secured websocket in the installer of the desktop application does not sound very secure. How can I still encrypt the traffic? Do I have to encrypt the traffic if it does not leave the system?
- How to verify that a web page / client is really served under the domain that the user previously accepted as to be trusted? If the web page/client is served by a web server with a SSL certificate, can I use this information somehow for desktop app-side validation of the client resp. that the client is not running under a fake domain?
- How to verify that the contacted desktop application is not a malicious application using the same port to intercept incoming traffic?

Does somebody as some tips or pointers to "good practices"?